# Convert Option<&[u8]> to Option<Vec<u8>> in Rust?

Tags: rust

How do I convert an `Option<&[u8]>` to an `Option<Vec<u8>>`?

Comment: just by doing it ? what is the problem ?

Comment: @Stargateur Post code?

Answer (score 0):

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: Option<&[u8]> = Some(&[1, 2, 3]);
    let b: Option<Vec<u8>> = a.map(Vec::from);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

```
Some([1, 2, 3])
```

Or even this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: Option<&[u8]> = Some(&[1, 2, 3]);
    let b: Option<Vec<u8>> = a.map(Into::into);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

```rust
Some([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `o.map(ToOwned::to_owned)` best expresses the intent: getting an owned version of something not owned.

Comment: A `Vec` isn’t *just* an owned slice. I would find this confusing.

Answer (score -2):

One possible solution is to use `Option.map()` with a closure (lambda function).

```
/// (Pseudocode)
let maybe_slice = Option<&[u8]>;

let maybe_vec = maybe_slice.map(
    |slice| {
        return Vec::from(slice);
    }
);
```

However this leads to a slightly awkward set of lines to format a closure in a readable way.

---

As an aside, if you are wondering why the variables are called `maybe_slice` and `maybe_vec`, this is to make it clear the variable is of type `Option<T>`. Everywhere you see the prefix `maybe_` you immediately know you are dealing with an optional.

For `Result` types, I have taken to using `result_` as a prefix, but I don't personally like this as much. `maybe_` could also have been used for `Result` types, but then `optional_` or something would have to be used for `Option` types.

Comment: Actually, you can get a much less verbose alternative, which is `maybe_slice.map(Vec::from)` (no need for a closure), or if you really want to have a closure, you can use `maybe_slice.map(|slice| Vec::from(slice))`. It's quite rare to use the `return` keyword, but I've actually never seen it used in a closure at all.

Comment: @jthulhu Yes I like that, it's also very clear what it does

Comment: @Finomnis What else would you call the variable `maybe_vec` or `maybe_slice`?

Comment: @Finomnis Consider the following. Imaging the slice contains data about a "Cat". If I put the Cat into an Option, I do not have a Cat. I have an optional_cat, or a maybe_cat. I certainly do not have "a cat". The type is neither a Cat, nor is it certain to contain data about a Cat. Further, when I `unwrap` the optional_cat, I get a cat. `cat = optional_cat.unwrap()`. Clearly `cat = cat.unwrap()` is wrong.

Comment: @Finomnis By the way - I am familiar with the Clean Code meme - which part of that article do you think *disagrees* with this convention?

Comment: @Finomnis It's pretty obvious what that's supposed to be representing

Comment: @Finomnis I don't agree that writing pseudcode makes the answer inherently bad.

Comment: @Finomnis Make an edit if you want